Sufficient statistic as iso-surfaces in the distribution density. Is it possible to generalise to multiple parameters?
For continuous distributions, there is a geometric intuition behind sufficient statistics that regards a multivariate probability density as several iso-surfaces.
This works at least for cases where a distribution has a single sufficient statistic. See for instance Fisher in  A mathematical examination of the methods of determining the accuracy of an observation by the mean error, and the mean square error. (1920)

This unique superiority of $\sigma_2$ is dependent on the form of the normal curve, $$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx \,,$$ which leads to a frequency density in generalised space distributed on concentric spheres.

and when searching for a distribution that relates to $\sigma_1$ we have

$$\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} e^{-\frac{|x-m|}{\sigma} \sqrt{2}}dx \,,$$ replaces the generalised spheres by generalised octahedra, upon the surface of which $\sigma_1$ is constant, provided $\bar{x} =m$.


Can we make this geometric intuition of spheres, octahedra, or generally any surface, also for cases with where the sufficient statistic has more than 1 dimension?
